# Crystal Reports 2013 Referencing multi-value parameter in command

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I have a multi-value parameter called Category, listing out all the different procedure categories that can be queried.  How does one reference this parameter in the command. The following code does not appear to work

```
1. and  (i.PROC_CAT_ID in ({?Category}))
2. and  (i.PROC_CAT_ID =  ({?Category}))
```

Any suggestions for making this work?

Thanks, Jeannie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its a multiparameter then two conditions are not needed. try likw below

```
and  (i.PROC_CAT_ID in [{?Category}])
```

In the above case `[{?Category}]` should a `,` saperated value, if its not then convert into comma saperated value and use it